# How can I change the Font Size and Weight for the Back Arrow and Back Text in a Navigation Page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I had a similar question on how to change the font of the title which is here:

[How can I change the Font Size and Weight for the Header in a Navigation Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48502373/how-can-i-change-the-font-size-and-weight-for-the-header-in-a-navigation-page)

Now I have that changed does anyone know how to also change the font size and weight for the top back arrow and the message that goes with it at the top of a navigation page? Seems like these are not part of the title as they have retained the original font size and weight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this issue only occurs on iOS platform, so the solution is

Set `UIBarButtonItem Appearance` in `FinishedLaunching` in  `AppDelegate`

```
UITextAttributes att = new UITextAttributes();
att.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(20.0 , FontAttributes.Bold); // size and weight

UIBarButtonItem.AppearanceWhenContainedIn(new Type[] { typeof( UINavigationBar) }).SetTitleTextAttributes(att, UIControlState.Normal);
UIBarButtonItem.AppearanceWhenContainedIn(new Type[] { typeof(UINavigationBar) }).SetTitleTextAttributes(att,  UIControlState.Highlighted);
```

Comment: Hello Cole,  Can you add some more about the "FinishedLaunching" in AppDelegate.  I was not even aware there was such a thing. I assume FinishedLaunching is a method but what is AppDelegate?

Comment: @Alan2 AppDelegate.cs is entrance of iOS platform as a class in iOS project .

Comment: Xia - Sorry for the long delay in answering. I tried this but it's giving me an error here: UITextAttributes att = new UITextAttributes();
            att.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(20.0, FontAttributes.Bold); // size and weight    Cannot convert from double to system nfloat and cannot convert to UIKit.uifontweight

Comment: @Alan2  change to `UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(20.0f, UIFontWeight.Bold);`