# Change navigation page bar color and title color

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Tabbed page attached is a Navigation page I want to change the color or the bar itself and the title color but I am getting a exception:

> **(System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)**

How can I change the color of my navigation bar and title color?

Here is my tabbed page xaml code:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TBSApp.View"
        x:Class="TBSApp.Tabbed_Page.TabPage"
        NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
        xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
        android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
        BarBackgroundColor="#fff"
        android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="#bbbbbb"
        android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="#fc5661">
<NavigationPage Title="Dashboard" Icon="home.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <local:Dashboard />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
```

Here is my Dashboard.xaml.cs code:

```
((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#fff");
((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).BarTextColor = Color.FromHex("#203341");
```

Comment: Did this code ((NavigationPage)Application.Current.MainPage).BarBackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#fff"); work?

Comment: @AndroDevil nope

Comment: Did you solved this?

Comment: @AndroDevil yes see my answer below

Comment: Ok. good to know

Comment: @AndroDevil my only question now is how can I change the font type of the title?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497048/how-can-i-change-the-font-for-the-header-of-a-navigation-page-with-xamarin-forms

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto did you find an answer or do you still need help

Comment: @G.hakim I found the answer my problems now are how to change the font type of the title and position the title to center

Comment: Do you want it to be on both iOS and Android?

Comment: @G.hakim yes if possible can I use <ResourceDictionary> to achieve that?

Comment: No resource dictionary is just static resources it is not related to this, you can create a style but you might have to do some native implementation here

Comment: Can you help me how?

Comment: This doesn't work because MainPage is a TabbedPage.  If you want to modify the Navigation page from within Dashboard, just refer to the Navigation property.  You are making this more complex than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
            <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="#fff"/>
            <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="#203341"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Can't I need to wait 2 days before I can mark it

Comment: this doenst work in all versions of xamarin. it doesnt work at the version ending on .2012, but works on the newest version. unfortunately, using the newer version of xamarin forms sometimes just hides my nav bar without any way of getting it back. so i am stuck using the .2012 version in which i cannot change the color

Answer (score 0):

Use "CurrentPageChanged" event then you can able to change the colour and title of the navigation bar

Here is code snippet hope this will work

```
public Dashboard()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CurrentPageChanged += ChangeTitle;
} 

private void ChangeTitle(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ((NavigationPage)Parent).BarBackgroundColor = Color.White;
    BarBackgroundColor = Device.RuntimePlatform == Color.White;
}
```