# Custom Tabbed Page - custom tabs

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-customtabs

I'm trying to make a custom tabbed page of which each tab has a certain shape.
It's not too complex, I only need to change the cornerradius in fact of 1 side of a tab.

Now, I have been able to make a custom tab and change some stuff like bckground colors, fonts, etc
But I have not been able to make a tab in any shape I want.
Searching Google & other sources have not been able to solve my problem.

An example of what I'm trying to achieve:
[Merch tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U4B7.png)
[Profile Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwX51.png)

[ticket tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgKYe.png)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: That seems too complex for Xamarin, the only way I can think of you getting a design like you want to use tabs images backgrounds with the shape you desire.

Comment: In that case, how would an image be implemented?

Comment: You could maybe do it natively! But that would be time taking

Comment: I don't care tbh, as long as I have what I want :p

Comment: [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55058635/change-navigation-page-bar-color-and-title-color/55065280#55065280) to get selected tab and then do respectively changes

Comment: Improved formating

Comment: @SergioAMG what you mean by " too complex for Xamarin"? you think that's possible using Java?